# Flutter Logger Package not printing Emoji, colors

Tags: flutter, debugging, logging, flutter-dependencies, flutter-debug

I am using flutter Logger Package

```
logger: ^2.0.1
```

I am using all the default settings they mentioned

```
    var logger = Logger(
  printer: PrettyPrinter(
      methodCount: 2, // Number of method calls to be displayed
      errorMethodCount: 8, // Number of method calls if stacktrace is provided
      lineLength: 120, // Width of the output
      colors: true, // Colorful log messages
      printEmojis: true, // Print an emoji for each log message
      printTime: false // Should each log print contain a timestamp
  ),
);
```

**Expected OUTPUT:**
[image]

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**
[image]

Comment: It is a known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64491 also mentioned inside the plugin as well.